# Use IF condition to get a query inside a UNION in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to do the following(sample). Without using a **temp table** or **exec**.

```
SELECT 'apple' fruit, 'Dog' animal, 'crow' bird
UNION
 IF ('B' = 'A') BEGIN   SELECT 'orange' fruit, 'cat' animal, 'cock' bird
 END ELSE   SELECT 'grape' fruit, 'lion' animal, 'parrot' bird  END
UNION
SELECT 'banana' fruit, 'tiger' animal, 'hen' bird
```

Comment: What are `'A'` and `'B'`?  You should elaborate on this.

Comment: used as a dummy condition.

Comment: Please show us the actual query.  If it can't easily fit, then abbreviate as much as you need to, to get the point across.

Answer (score 3):

We can try phrasing the middle query in the union using `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT 'apple' fruit, 'Dog' animal, 'crow' bird
UNION ALL
SELECT
    CASE WHEN <some_condition> THEN 'orange' ELSE 'grape' END,
    CASE WHEN <some_condition> THEN 'cat'    ELSE 'lion' END,
    CASE WHEN <some_condition> THEN 'cock'   ELSE 'parrot' END
UNION ALL
SELECT 'banana', 'tiger', 'hen';
```

Tip: Only the aliases from the first query in a union will be used.  The others will just be ignored, so there is no point in adding aliases elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you @Tim. But I have given a sample query. I have large queries in the if and else cant use case for that.

Comment: Please address the question given under your question.

Comment: that 'A' and 'B' are just sample values. that's also an inner query condition like 'if((select top 1 value from SystemConfig where name='SpotlightQuarterGrades')='true')'

Comment: I have a large query, which has many unions and one of the union needs a checking to get the correct query to execute based on the condition. So don't know what to do with it. Please help me.

Comment: I think my solution should still work, even if the condition for the `CASE` expressions happen to be subqueries.

Comment: The query is selecting some students with some details. Not the manual data like I have given in the sample(Sorry for the confusion). My concern is based on the if condition I have to choose an entire select query(which has already have many cases and table joins). In this case also ?

Comment: @Akhil _Please_ stop commenting here, thanks.  Address the question I have asked under your original question.